# splitting a dict-like varchar column into multiple columns using SQL presto

Tags: sql, presto, trino

I have a column in a table that is varchar but has a dictionary-like format. Some rows have more key-value pairs (for example first row has 3 pairs and second row has 4 pairs).
For example:

| column |
| --- |
| {"customerid":"12345","name":"John", "likes":"Football, Running"} |
| {"customerid":"54321","name":"Sam", "likes":"Art", "dislikes":"Hiking"} |

I need a query that can "explode" the column like so:

| customerid | name | likes | dislikes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | John | Football, Running |  |
| 54321 | Sam | Art | Hiking |

No extra rows are added. Just extra columns (There are other already existing columns in the table).

I've tried casting the varchar column to an array and then using UNNEST function but it doesn't work. I think that method creates extra rows.

I am using Prestosql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data looks like json, so you can parse and process it:

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset (column) AS (
    VALUES ('{"customerid":"12345","name":"John", "likes":"Football, Running"}' ),
        ('{"customerid":"54321","name":"Sam", "likes":"Art", "dislikes":"Hiking"}')
) 

--query
select json_extract_scalar(json_parse(column), '$.customerid') customerid,
    json_extract_scalar(json_parse(column), '$.name') name,
    json_extract_scalar(json_parse(column), '$.likes') likes,
    json_extract_scalar(json_parse(column), '$.dislikes') dislikes
from dataset
```

Output:

| customerid | name | likes | dislikes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | John | Football, Running |  |
| 54321 | Sam | Art | Hiking |

In case of many columns you can prettify it by casting to parsed json to map (depended on contents it can be `map(varchar, varchar)` or `map(varchar, json)`):

```sql
--query
select m['customerid'] customerid,
    m['name'] name,
    m['likes'] likes,
    m['dislikes'] dislikes
from (
    select cast(json_parse(column) as map(varchar, varchar)) m
    from dataset
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, the first query worked. The second one outputs an error though -- `INVALID_CAST_ARGUMENT: Cannot cast to map(varchar, varchar). Unexpected token when cast to varchar:`

Comment: @codenoodles this means that your test and actual data differ (actual json data types). You can try `select transform_values(cast(json_parse(column) as map(varchar, json)), (k, v) -> json_format(v))` for inner select which should mimic the behaviour of the first query.